# Python Character Limiter

Tags: python, string

How can I limit a string based on character count, and in the same time preserve complete words ?

I just don't want to slice, but even want to preserve the complete words. Please guide me ..

**Edit**

*Example*

```
string = "stackoverflow rocks , I know it."
```

so I need a function, for example

```
limiter(string,5)
```

which should return a complete word (`stackoverflow` in this example), even if the limit I have set is 5. Thus preserving the meaning of words..

```
limiter(string,25)
```

desired result

```
stackoverflow rocks , I know
```

Thanks !

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you elaborate? How do you envision using this?

Comment: Is the character limit hard?  I.e., do you want to make the last word go over the character count, or make the last full word stop before the character count is reached?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you want to do is word-wrapping a string then a simple approach is the following:

1. Begin looking at character `start + max_width`
2. Go backward one character at a time until you find a word breaking char
3. If you found one then split there, if you reached instead `start` then nothing can be done and just print out the whole line

Answer (score 5):

Will this work for you?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def limiter(x, limit):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if i >= limit and x[i] == " ":
            break
    return x[:i]

def main():
    x = "stackoverflow rocks , I know it."
    print limiter(x, 5)
    print limiter(x, 25)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Do if `limit >= len(x): return x` and change your loop to `range(limit, len(x))` and you won't need to go through all the characters below the limit.